# React - How to prevent <a href> from refreshing

Tags: reactjs, onclick, router, preventdefault

I have an  that links to another stateless component.
I have an onClick listener that calls a method that calls e.preventDefault(), but this just makes the  not link to anywhere when clicked.

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.preventRefresh = this.preventRefresh.bind(this);
}

<a href={/components/Button'} onClick={this.preventRefresh}>{n.componentName}</a>

preventRefresh(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

So clicking on the  does nothinh. How can I prevent the page from reloading?

Comment: not understood at all, please clerify your question, better add some code as example...

Comment: What do you want your link to do? If you prevent the default behavior, you can do whatever you like in the `preventRefresh` callback.

Comment: Fix this:
> I have an (?) that ...
> So clicking on the (?) doest nothing

Answer (score 2):

In React, this doesn't works:

```
<a href={/components/Button'} onClick={this.preventRefresh}>{n.componentName}</a>
```

You can't set the href attribute to a component (a component is not a URL)

If you want to make a navigation link, you should use react-router-dom (if you are working for browsers):

Fist, you have to install it:

```
npm install --save react-router-dom
```

Then you can use it, check the official example:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
);

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
);

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>Components</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>Props v. State</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic} />
    <Route
      exact
      path={match.url}
      render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
    />
  </div>
);

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
);

export default BasicExample;
```

And check the docs [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)